Infinite House Number Problem
He said the house of his friend was in a long street, numbered on this side one, two, three, and so on, and that all the numbers on one side of him added up exactly the same as all the numbers on the other side of him. Funny thing that! He said he knew there was more than fifty houses on that side of the street, but not so many as five hundred.
What House number did his friend live in?

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question?
